# First Capital Letter of each word

Tags: looker-studio, uppercase

I am using Google Data studio to create reports, and the data is directly obtained from Google Analytics. Is about web traffic measurement.

The thing is that I want to visualize top categories..

So the data is in a "URL" presentation, for example.. /entradas/**delicias-de-delhi**/

"/delicias-de-delhi/" is a product, one of thousands of products from lots of categories.

I would like to visualize in graphs or tables, top products and that kind of staff, but with their names in this format:**Delicias de Delhi**.

I figured out how to get rid of slashs "/" and hyphens "-" , the thing is I also want to have capital letters in the first letter of each word. I tried using Upper() function, but that converts everything in Capital Letters. **DELICIAS DE DELHI, and that is not what i want to achieve.**

I would really appreciate some help !

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Data Studio does not support this feature. Normally regex replace would be the way to do it, but at https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax it says it "does not support" various operations relating to upper / lower case for text.

Comment: @GavinHaynes there is a ugly workaround to do that task of uppercasing all words.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT_TEXT(dummy,1)),SUBSTR(dummy,2,20))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.